# How to get controller name within controller | symfony5

Tags: symfony5

I want to use controller name in one of the function inside my controller:

```
class HomepageController extends AbstractController
{
  /**
   * @Route("/homepage/add", name="add_homepage", methods={POST})
   */
  public function addHomepage(Request $request)
  {
    $data = json_decode($request->getContent(), true);
    $controllerName = "Homepage" //this is what i want
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it this way:

```
public function qls(Request $request): Response
{
    $routeName = $request->attributes->get("_route");
}
```